# I am trying to run this OpenCV program, but i am not able to load the image

Tags: opencv

The image file is present in the same directory in which my project is located still i am unable to load the image . I have tried giving the full path still it is unable to load image . I am working on Ubuntu

Code:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
cv::Mat image =cv::imread("lena.gif");
 if (!image.data)
{
    std::cout << "Image not loaded";
return -1;

}
cv::namedWindow("Lena",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::imshow("Lena",image);
cv::waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try putting a copy in `/tmp` and changing the path, just to be sure. I chose that because a) you can write there, b) it is absolute and c) it has no spaces.

Comment: It is displaying this error : Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/us4/Public/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 312
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/us4/Public/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:312: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

Comment: Try grabbing a different GIF off the Net somewhere just to test in case yours is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks man it worked with a new image

Comment: Excellent - good luck with your project!